# When subscribing to a product on Amazon, is it possible to specify a price threshold? (in case the product's price increases significantly)

Tags: amazon

When subscribing to a product on Amazon, is it possible to specify a price threshold? (so that if the product's price increases significantly, the subscription is stopped or placed on hold)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When subscribing to a product on Amazon, it currently is not possible to specify a price threshold.